# In this clipper circuit, what is the value of output voltage when the diode is off?

Tags: diodes

[image: schematic]

I am having confusion over what value the output waveform will take when the input voltage has negative half cycle (so that diode is reverse biased). In my intuition, the diode acts as open circuit and output voltage should be 2V. And during positive half cycle, the output voltage is still 2V for Vin < 2V(as diode is still reverse biased) and then follow Vin for all other values of Vin.

The problem is that I don't get the same answer as my textbook depicts. My answer looks something like this:
[image: Sorry for the rough figure. Please consider it.]

Is this the correct way, or am I wrong?

Edit: The Texbook says: [image]

Comment: What does the textbook predict?

Comment: Kevin White, Just edited the question with the answer from textbook.

Comment: I agree - they've got the answer wrong.  It would give that if the diode was reversed. Your answer is right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're right! I added a function generator to the input of your circuit, and then plotted V(in) and V(out). Take a look at this quick simulation:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ferwZz.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The result matches your sketch, not the textbook's answer.